# Force DispatcherTimer tick

Tags: windows-phone-7, time

I need to send a server request about once per minute, to get a new products list (in case it was changed via web).

So, i'm using DispatcherTimer

```
public static void Start()
    {
        if (timer != null) return;

        timer = new DispatcherTimer {Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1)};
        timer.Tick += Run;
        timer.Start();
    }

private static async void Run(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60); // TODO" add dynamic changes here
        timer.Stop();
        ** Do stuff
        timer.Start();
    }
```

However, sometimes, i need to force updating. Is it correct to run

```
public static void ForceUpdate()
    {
        Run(null, null);
    }
```

EDIT: i mean, if *Do stuff* is long enough, wouldn't it be called second time via timer? Or maybe i should use something else for this kind of job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, well, it is quite simple

```
        public static void ForceUpdate()
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
            timer.Start();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Insert a variable which should store the last update time and check if update had been done in a certain interval.

Comment: Thk for answer, but it is not exactly what i was looking for. I just edited question.

Comment: Yep. Just made a test app - actually, i can make it non-async, and check **if (!timer.IsEnabled) return;** However, if it would be forced during the running, user would need to wait 60 seconds for another Run().

Comment: Tried **public static void ForceUpdate()
            {
                timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
            }**, but setting interval is not forcing timer to react on it.